# How can I configure my computer (localhost) to assign dynamic IP addresses to virtual machines made by virtual box?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, ip, dhcp, localhost

How can I configure my computer (localhost) to assign dynamic IP addresses to virtual machines made by virtual box?

Note: I am using Ubuntu Desktop LTS 16.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking.  Do you want to use bridged networking and run a DHCP server on your host?  If not, then Virtualbox has its own DHCP server if you use NAT or Host-only networking.

Comment: I want to PXE boot them from my local host. All the virtual machines are inside my computer. However, PXE booting seems to need some DHCP configuration. How can I do that?

Comment: The answer is exactly the same as if you had some physical computers on your network that you want to PXE boot.  You'll need to set up a PXE boot server on your host.  Once you get that running, use bridged networking for your VM's.

Comment: Can you help me how can I configure that? I am a beginner in Linux and networking. I am getting an error when I execute: cp -fr install/netboot/* /var/lib/tftpboot/

Comment: This is the error: cp: cannot stat 'install/netboot/*': No such file or directory

Comment: I couldn't find the netboot directiry. What did I miss! I followed this guide: https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-install-pxe-server-on-ubuntu-16-04/